# How to return all of Enum instances with name + fields in Java?

Tags: java, enums

I have:

```java
@Getter
@AllArgumentsConstructor
public enum Fruit {

    APPLE("red"),
    ORANGE("yellow");

    private final String color;
    ....
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Frunit test() {
        return Fruit.APPLE;
    }
}
```

My expected response is:

```
APPLE("red")
```

and an actual response is:

```
APPLE
```

I want to have a response `Enum.value` with the field of instance, and furthermore - all of Enum list like this:

```
{ APPLE("red"), ORANGE("yellow") }
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Override `toString()` method inside your enum:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name() + "(\"" + color + "\")";
}
```